# Location of python source code in Jython/Java integration

Tags: java, python, integration, jython

I could integrate the java/jython from [this source](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/Scripting.html).

I downloaded the `jython` with `brew`, so the jar file is located in `/usr/local/Cellar/jython` directory.

I came up with the following script to build the class file into the _build directory, but the issue is that I had to copy the python (jython) source into the directory also to make the integration work.

```
#!/bin/bash

DIRECTORY="_build"
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
    mkdir $DIRECTORY
fi

cp Building.py $DIRECTORY
javac -d _build -cp .:/usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.5.3/libexec/jython.jar *.java
java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/jython/2.5.3/libexec/jython.jar:_build org.jython.book.Main
```

My question is how to locate the jython source anywhere I like and teach java code to find the jython files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setupPath() method should be added into the JythonObjectFactory first.

```
public static void setupPath(String[] paths)
{
    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();

    interpreter.exec("import sys;");
    for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        interpreter.exec(String.format("sys.path.append(\"%s\")", paths[i]));
    }
}
```

Then, in the Main function, this function should be invoked.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JythonObjectFactory factory = JythonObjectFactory.getInstance();
        ArithType a = (ArithType) factory.createObject(ArithType.class, "Arith");

        String[] paths = {"DIRECTORY1", "DIRECTORY2"};
        JythonObjectFactory.setupPath(paths);                        
        ...
```